# Settings crashes when I try to set a screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, twrp, google-pixel

I have a Google Pixel. The bootloader is unlocked, but the system software remains unmodified.

A few days ago, I booted into TWRP (`flashboot boot twrp.img`) to access the data partition. The encryption key for the data partition is encrypted with a key that is partly derived from the unlock code. I was under the impression that touchscreen input with TWRP would be very mininal due to it being a minimal recovery system, so I had figured that I would not be able to enter my password so TWRP could then mount the data partition. I search the internet for this question and the results said to remove the lock screen password. I did that and I was able to access the data partition while booted into TWRP.

I rebooted my phone into normal Android and I successfully set my lock screen password again, BUT I may be misremembering this and it may have been that I had unset my password, then set it back up, and THEN booted into TWRP for the first time. The problem now is that when I either:

- Go into Settings and select `Security & location > Screen lock`
- Press the box at the top of the main menu in Settings that says "Secure your phone"

Settings crashes. Now I cannot set a screen lock. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

These are not solutions:

- Wiping my phone.
- Restoring from a backup.
- Anything to do with syncing with Google.

Comment: If you have Android 8+ you can change the lock screen via adb: https://www.theandroidsoul.com/change-remove-lockscreen-pattern-pin-password-adb-android-oreo/

Comment: @Robert Sounds too risky. I think I might lose the key that is used to decrypt my data if I do that.