# TWRP asking for a password when one is not set

Tags: twrp

My smartphone is the original Google Pixel. The bootloader on this device is unlocked. A week or so ago, I decided to boot into TWRP to do some stuff with my data. Before booting into it the first time, I removed my unlock pattern because I didn't know how I'd go about entering an unlock pattern in TWRP. After booting into TWRP the first time and then booting back into normal Android, I set my unlock pattern, I think, and then I removed it again. Afterwards, I was unable to (and I am still unable to) set a screen lock password/PIN/pattern. I'm pretty sure this is tied into [this problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215784/settings-crashes-when-i-try-to-set-a-screen-lock).

The first time that I booted into TWRP, it did NOT ask for a decryption pattern; I think I was able to see files inside directories like `/data/user/0`. Right now, when I boot into TWRP, it asks me for my password in order to decrypt. The only problem with that is that *I don't have a password  set*. When Android boots up, I'm not asked for a PIN, a password, or a pattern, and I can see all of my contacts, files, applications, and so on.

Are my inability to set a password in Settings and TWRP asking for a password to decrypt folders like `/data/user/0` (TWRP doesn't actually mention any directories) linked? How can I fix this?

These solutions are not acceptable:

- Performing a factory reset.
- Anything having to do with syncing with Google.

Comment: Hello If the answer to the linked question or the password "android" doesn't work, or if the device is not encrypted to begin with, let me know. I'll reopen your question.

Comment: @Firelord This is not a duplicate. I am trying to fix a very different problem.

Comment: As I said I can reopen but can you at least explain how the two questions are different. Did the answer there not work for you? Have you already tried it?

Comment: @Firelord I have not tried that answer, but now I'm not able to try it because I have encountered [another problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216137/google-pixel-is-stuck-at-pixel-is-starting).